# Java application consumes more CPU cycles

Tags: java

we noticed that our application consumes 99% CPU cycle in Linux and we identified that a thread running in an indefinite loop, which causes this issue. we noticed a strange behavior on this. Based on parameters, this thread schedule a timer task. if the timer task is scheduled the CPU usage went down to 20%. If it's not scheduled CPU usage is 100%. Just curious to know how introducing an another processing thread brings down the CPU usage to 10-20%.

```
public void run() 
    {
        log.info("Starting VCMG Channel Thread...");
        while (true) {

            if (readPacket()) {

                LoyaltyMessageHandle mh = null;

                synchronized(this) 
                {
                    if(map.containsKey(respSTAN)) 
                    {

                        mh = (LoyaltyMessageHandle) map.get(respSTAN);
                        mh.setLoyaltyResp(loyaltyObject);
                        resetHeartBeatTimer();
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        //Just drop the packet on the floor... It probably timedout.
                        if (!log.isDebugEnabled()) 
                        {
                            log.warn("Packet: [" + new String(loyaltyObject).substring(0,28) + 
                                "...] DROPPED !!!!!");
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            log.debug("Packet: [" + new String(loyaltyObject) + "] DROPPED !!!!!");
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(mh != null) {
                    synchronized(mh) {
                        mh.notify();
                    }
                }
            } 
        }

    }

 public synchronized void resetHeartBeatTimer()
    {
        if (heartBeatTimer != null) 
        {
            heartBeatTimer.cancel();
        }
        startHeartBeat();
    }

 public synchronized void startHeartBeat() 
    {
        heartBeatTimeOut = loyaltyMgr.getHeartBeatInactiveTimer() * 1000;

        // Timeout value zero indicates that the 'heartbeat' needs to be disabled.
        // If the timeout value is less than zero that should be ignored since that will cause exception.
        if ((heartBeatTimeOut > 0) && (this.clientSocket.isConnected())) 
        {
            if (heartBeatTimeOut < HEART_BEAT_LOWEST_TIMEOUT) 
            {
                heartBeatTimeOut = HEART_BEAT_LOWEST_TIMEOUT;
            }
            heartBeatTimer = new HeartBeatTimer(this, loyaltyMgr.getHeartbeatTimeout());
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(heartBeatTimer, heartBeatTimeOut);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should look at the code. Or let us.

Comment: Without seeing the code, I don't see how we can help you besides making wild guesses.

Comment: Either you designed you thread to busy loop or you didn't. If you didn't, it's a bug and you should fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Because if a loop is running tight with no "sleep" then it is just using the CPU

If you put a sleep in or otherwise make contention possible with the thread then the CPU isn't being used

Your timer must be sleeping the loop and so it is using less CPU time

Comment: Yes That's what is happening, a loop is running indefinitely which causes this issue. this we can fix by adding a sleep. Scheduling timer task spawn a new thread which is going to consume CPU cycle as well. But I am not sure how CPU usage went down when a timer task is scheduled.